# Unattended generation of an ECDSA key using gpg2

Tags: bash, cryptography, gnupg, elliptic-curve, ecdsa

**Short question**

How do I specify an elliptic curve in a gpg2 v2.1.11 parameter file?

**Long question**

I have successfully used the following bash script to generate an RSA key using gpg2 v2.1.11:

```
#!/bin/bash

PUBRING_FILE=$(mktemp /tmp/pub.XXXXXX)
CONFIG_FILE=$(mktemp /tmp/config.XXXXXX)

cat >$CONFIG_FILE <<EOF
    Key-Type: DSA
    Key-Length: 1024
    Subkey-Type: RSA
    Subkey-Length: 2048
    Name-Real: Name
    Name-Comment: Comment
    Name-Email: Email
    Expire-Date: 0
    Passphrase: abc
    %pubring $PUBRING_FILE
EOF

gpg2 --quiet --batch --expert --full-gen-key $CONFIG_FILE
```

I want to use the same script to generate an ECDSA key. However, when I replace

```
Subkey-Type: RSA
Subkey-Length: 2048
```

with

```
Subkey-Type: ECDSA
Subkey-Length: 256
```

I get the following error

> *gpg: key generation failed: Unknown elliptic curve*

My configuration file clearly omits the curve, but how can I include it? I.e., how do I specify an elliptic curve in a gpg2 v2.1.11 parameter file?

Comment: Please provide the full version of GnuPG you're using.

Comment: Sorry, it was implicit. I'm using v2.1.11.

Answer (score 2):

`gpg2` does not know which EC curve you want to use. To fix this, you need to use the `Key-Curve` option. In your example you should remove the `Subkey-Length: 2048` line and add a new `Subkey-Curve: [...]` option.

Example using the NIST P-256 curve:

```
cat >$CONFIG_FILE <<EOF
    Key-Type: DSA
    Key-Length: 1024
    Subkey-Type: ECDSA
    Subkey-Curve: nistp256
    Name-Real: Name
    Name-Comment: Comment
    Name-Email: Email
    Expire-Date: 0
    Passphrase: abc
    %pubring $PUBRING_FILE
EOF
```